# how to add images dynamically to a button background in salesforce lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am finding difficulty to set an image dynamically as a background for the button. I can able to get static image from resource but I could not load in dynamic

Comment: Hi Murali, you've posted a number of very broad or vague questions. Could you take a moment to read through [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back to edit this question by adding what you've tried and including your code and any error messages you're seeing?

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet? Just your button markup should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using :

`<img src="/[namespace]/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/[id]"/>`

where id is the content version id(prefix 068).